# ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I face the below error, What is it exactly, and what can I do for it?

> ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css
>   ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: Please include the code that causes the error.. Which code makes this error?? If it caused while adding css, then you need to run ```npm install --save @zeit/next-css``` and configure in ```next.config.js```  file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you may have a look the latest [next.js 9.3 blogs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets)

Next.js 9.2 introduced built-in support for Global `CSS` Stylesheets to replace the `next-css` plugin with better defaults to provide a more optimized result.

Right after the release we increasingly got asked to integrate Sass support as many businesses moving to Next.js have an existing design system based on Sass.

To get started using global Sass imports in your application, `install sass`:

```
npm install sass
```

Then, import the Sass or CSS or both file within `pages/_app.js`.

And remove all other `sass`, `CSS` supported plugins like which @Zeit provided before.

Then restart/rebuild again.

The Next.js 9.3 is very simple.